# How to remove fasta formatted sequences that contain Ns

Tags: perl, awk, fasta

I have a fasta file like such

```
">ENS..._intronX
acgtacgtacgtacgt
">ENS..._intronY
acgtacgtNNNNa
acgtacgtacgtacgt
">ENS..._intronZ
acgtacgtacgtacgt
acgtacgtacgtacgt
```

I need to remove sequences with at least 2 `N` in a row (because these introns are misannotated).

Here, it would be sequence  `" >ENS..._intronY "` (Line 3, 4, and 5 should be removed)

any suggestions?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk)

```
awk -v RS='">' '!/NN/{printf $0RT}' file
">ENS..._intronX
acgtacgtacgtacgt
">ENS..._intronZ
acgtacgtacgtacgt
acgtacgtacgtacgt
```

Comment: Should be N+ instead of NNNN as you originally posted?

Comment: @BugKiller, sigh, the `N` in `ENS` causes all records to not qualify

Comment: downvoter, i guess this is to do with awk not being the right tool to parse fasta files, but do explain

Comment: The OP's specs require omitting fasta records whose sequence contains two or more Ns.  Your script doesn't work on a sequence that contains (for example) `acgtacgtNNa`.  Also, fasta records begin with `>` and not `">`--even though the OP shows the double-quotes character.

Comment: @Kenosis - th,e first part is easily fixed, the OP seems to have edited and added that detail later. On the second point, good to know but all i can do not knowing the first thing about fasta is work off the OP's sample data

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears you're pursuing bioinformatics, consider becoming familiar with [Bio::SeqIO](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.922/Bio/SeqIO.pm), as it'll help with this and *many* other fasta parsing jobs:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $in = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file => shift, -format => 'Fasta' );

while ( my $seq = $in->next_seq() ) {
    print '>' . $seq->id . ' ' . $seq->desc . "\n" . $seq->seq . "\n"
      if $seq->seq !~ /nn/i;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output on your dataset:

```
>ENS..._intronX 
acgtacgtacgtacgt
>ENS..._intronZ 
acgtacgtacgtacgtacgtacgtacgtacgt
```

Hope this helps!